# MySQL SUM total minutes activated

Tags: mysql

I need to make the sum of the total minutes that a certain status has been activated.

[Example][1]

```
id     disp_id  state   created_at
764912  2         1       11/06/2018 12:03
765261  2         1       11/06/2018 12:08
765401  2         1       11/06/2018 12:10
765540  2         1       11/06/2018 12:12
765610  2         1       11/06/2018 12:13
765889  2         1       11/06/2018 12:17
766029  2         1       11/06/2018 12:19
766098  2         1       11/06/2018 12:20
766168  2         1       11/06/2018 12:21
766656  2         1       11/06/2018 12:28
```

i need this sum:

```
03->08 = 5 minutes
08->10 = 2 minutes
10->12 = 2 minutes
12->13 = 1 minutes
13->17 = 4 minutes
17->19 = 2 minutes
19->20 = 1 minutes
20->21 = 1 minutes
21->28 = 7 minutes
```

Total: 25 minutes

I tried (SUM(minute(a.created_at))) but i have the total sum of the minutes

03+08+10+12+13+17+19+20+21+28=151

Is it possible to perform this SQL using sum?

thank you!

Comment: convert them in unixtime and then subsctract the max and min time in same query and again convert the unixtime into the human time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below query.

```
SELECT CAST((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(created_at)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(created_at)))/60 as UNSIGNED)  AS 'minutes';
```

**Example**

```
SELECT CAST((UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-11 12:28:00') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-11 12:03:00'))/60 as UNSIGNED)  AS 'minutes';
```

Hope solution will help you.